# How to iterate a queryset list in a django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is there a way to iterate this list of querysets in the template?

```
[<Director: Roman Polanski>, <Director: Alfred Hitchcock>,
 <Director: Steven Spielberg>, <Director: David Lynch>]
```

I tried using a list syntax, but the django template language doesn't seem to accept lists, also.
 Thank you all.

Comment: Are you sure that's a list of `QuerySet` objects and not a list of Model instances?

Comment: If I ask python for the type it gives me this: <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>

Comment: Yes, that's an instance of a `QuerySet`, not at list of `QuerySet`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django's template language does of course accept lists!

Here is what the code in your template should look like:

```
{% for director in director_list %}
    {{ director }}
{% endfor %}
```

By the way: What you're having here is a queryset (that gets evaluated to a list), not a list of querysets.

Comment: Yes, I've done that, but what prints is the text I just gave as example, I want to get the attributes of each director. And thanks.

Comment: You need to add a `__str__()` method in your `Director` `ModelClass` that specifies what attributes should be printed **or** print the desired attributes directly (e.g. `{{ director.name }}`).